# How to create SSH tunnel using PuTTY in Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

I need to create SSH tunnel with PuTTY in Windows, that would do the same as this command in Linux:

```
ssh -fN -L 2000:SomeIp:2000 myusername@myLinuxBox
```

I tried many options in PuTTY, including setting source port in GUI to "2000" and destination to "SomeIp:2000". Destination is set to local (as the `-L` switch suggests).

I successfully login to my SSH box but port forward is not made.

Is this even possible in Windows, so that all the connections made by programs that use this port (2000) will go through this tunnel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably want to use `plink.exe` instead of the GUI client. The command line syntax is compatible iirc.

Comment: I've tried plink with  but it seems ports are not forwarded. How to check if ports are forwarded once you logged in to remote sshbox?

Comment: I don't know of any server-side command to view which tunnels have been created by clients. Perhaps someone on serverfault can help you there :-).

Comment: Regarding the investigation: The local port forwarding rule opens a listening port on the local side only. No forwarding is created (so there's nothing detect on the remote side), until you actually try to connect to the local port.

Answer (score 33):

With the PuTTY suite, you can set up a tunnel either using the PuTTY itself (GUI) or using the command-line tool `plink.exe`.

---

With the `plink.exe`, you use the same arguments as with the OpenSSH `ssh`, except for the `-f`, which does not have an equivalent in Windows.

```
plink.exe -N -L 2000:SomeIp:2000 myusername@myLinuxBox
```

Reference: [Using the command-line connection tool Plink](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html)

---

With the PuTTY, the `-L 2000:SomeIp:2000` translates to:

[image: PuTTY tunnel settings]

So it's actually, what you claim to have tried. If you have any problems, use the PuTTY event log to investigate:

[image: PuTTY event log]

The `-N` translates to the option *"Don't start a shell or command at all"*.

[image: PuTTY option Don't start a shell or command at all]

*But it probably does not make sense with a GUI client to enable it, as you get a window anyway, you just cannot do anything with it. See also the [PuTTY wish no-terminal-window](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/no-terminal-window.html).*

---

If you are going to use the tunnel to connect with PuTTY to another server, you can actually set up the tunnel as a part of the session settings with use of `plink` as a proxy, see: [PuTTY configuration equivalent to OpenSSH ProxyCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28926612/850848).

Answer (score 12):

Or you can wade through the putty GUI, which also allows this. See `Connection > SSH > Tunnels` on the left side with the option tree.

[image]

Comment: I have tried setting many different optins from GUi, but forward is still not working. How can i display all forwards after i login to my sshbox?

Answer (score 3):

The answers above mention two different ways of resolving the problem:

- using plink
- using putty GUI

I don't have plink and I can't download the plink.exe file (it is a closely monitored restricted environment) so used a different way to script the solution with a one-line script:

```
start putty -ssh myusername@myLinuxBox -pw my_pw -L 2000:localhost:2000
```

Store this in a batch file (file extension ".bat", e.g. "tunnel.bat"). So every time you double-click on this file the command is run and putty creates the ssh tunnel. If you want more tunnels just repeat this part

> -L 2000:localhost:2000

by changing the ports accordingly.

Comment: OK, but this does the same what Plink does.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sure. However, I can’t install plink as I lack privileges. But I do have putty and would like to script the solution. This is what my answer achieves.

Comment: OK, so maybe mention that in your answer. Ntb, Plink does not need any installation, just grab the .exe file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks - edits done. Exe downloads are blocked by the firewall so for me this is the only way to script the solution.

Answer (score 2):

"Source" port is a port number on the same machine from which you are running putty (eg. open this in your browser: 127.0.0.1:source). "Destination" is your remote port that you want to connect to from your local machine. It started to work after I realized this.