# MySQL-Python code to query a MYSQL database through an SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have access to a MySQL database through ssh,

Could someone direct me to a MySQL-python code that will let me do this?

I need to save my query results on my local WINDOWS computer,

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried using [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko)?

Comment: Paramiko is the best python module to do ssh tunneling. I have added here the code to do exactly what you require: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/forward.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH port forwarding to do this.. in fact first google hit looks to walk you through this exact thing:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/

And since you're on windows, translate that to using PuTTY:

https://intranet.cs.hku.hk/csintranet/contents/technical/howto/putty-portforward.jsp

You'll then connect to localhost:3306 with your python script, SSH will forward that over to the other machine and you'll end up connecting to the remote mysql instance.

Comment: I apologize; it seems my question is unclear,
I can manually ssh to the database and run queries,
I was wondering if you can lead me to a sample MySQL-PYTHON code that will do this for me?
Something [sample code] that has the whole connection + Query in it
Thanks

Comment: There's nothing special to do, simply open a mysql connection in python and do stuff. That's the beauty of ssh port forwarding, it makes it look like the mysql server is running locally.

Comment: But how can I direct the output to my local computer > output.txt, wont the output be stored on the server?

Comment: Nope, you'll be running your script on your local computer, so any output (or redirection of output) from that script will be on your local computer

Comment: I just realized you were on windows.. you'll have to use PuTTY to do the port forwarding.. it works the same, but you have that pretty GUI to work with. I updated the answer to point you to instructions on how to setup port forwarding using PuTTY - use port 3306

Comment: To be honest with you, that was not my question,
I was hoping to get some sample code that I could start from,
Something that shows me how to ssh and query,
I’m using Github to connect and its working fine with me,

Comment: OK, I managed to get a code example, and I got it to work on my system, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You need to open up an SSH Tunnel to your sql server and then you can run paramiko to connect locally to the port you are using locally. This is done quite easily in *nix systems and I am sure you can download ssh command line too for windows. Try putty or plink, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974131/how-to-create-ssh-tunnel-using-putty-in-windows). What I do is I run a shell script like so, then I execute my paramiko python script, then I kill the

```
ssh -N remote_server@54.221.226.240 -i ~/.ssh/my_ssh_key.pem -L 5433:localhost:5432 
python paramiko_connect.py
kill pkill -f my_ssh_key.pem  # kill using the pattern, 
#see ''ps aux | grep my_ssh_key.pem'' to see what it will kill
```

-N means don't execute any commands, -L is the local port to tunnel from, followed by the remotes server port, assuming you are connected to that server already.

Works like a charm for me for my postgres server & I did try it on mysql too.