# PuTTY configuration equivalent to OpenSSH ProxyCommand

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, portforwarding, openssh

I'm just trying to use PuTTY to get an SSH connection to my servers.
These servers allow incoming SSH connection only from another specific server ("MySshProxyingServer" in example below).

Using Linux this is no problem with the `ssh -W` command.

In PuTTY I can't find the options to create such a connection.

Example under Linux (`~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host MyHostToConnectTo
    Hostname xx.xx.xx.xx
    User root
    Identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ProxyCommand ssh MySshProxyServer -W %h:%p
```

Anyone knows how to use such a config in PuTTY?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to "jump a host", then using "local proxy command" is an overkill. Recent versions of PuTTY have this build-in. Go to *Connection > Proxy*, and in *"Proxy type"*, select *"SSH to proxy and use port forwarding"*. Then specify the details of the intermediate server below (like *Hostname*, *Port*, *Username*, *Password* [or load your private key to Pageant]).

[image]

*(It's actually an overkill for OpenSSH too, as it has more user friendly options for this purpose too, see [Does OpenSSH support multihop login?](https://superuser.com/q/1488097/213663))*

---

To answer your literal question: The equivalent in PuTTY is "local proxy command". You can use the [`plink.exe`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) with the [`-nc` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-ncmode) instead of the `ssh` with the `-W` switch:

[image: PuTTY local proxy]

The *"local proxy command"* is:

```
plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -P %proxyport -nc %host:%port
```

---

An alternative is to open a tunnel via the "MySshProxyServer" first using another instance of PuTTY (or Plink).

See for example:

- [How to create SSH tunnel using PuTTY in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974131/850848)
- *My* guide for [tunneling SFTP/SCP session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty). It's for WinSCP, but just use PuTTY instead of WinSCP in section [Connecting through the tunnel](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty_connecting).

Comment: if you're using key auth you may find useful this line:
`plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -ssh -i c:\keys\my_key.ppk -nc %host:%port`

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you still use password for your jumphost is the option for that with an example.

```
plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -pw %pass -P %proxyport -nc %host:%port
```

Comment: This might be a useful comment to my answer. But it is not a standalone answer to the question.

Comment: This answer was just what I was looking for! I've been trying to make this work using every config example I could find, but I kept getting "Access Denied". By the way, enabling "Print proxy diagnostics in the terminal window" helped me realize this was a problem. I was finally able to get in after adding the `-pw` setting. So thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we want **ssh** to `172.16.0.21` via `8.8.8.8`

login name in both hosts is `john`

path to private key is `C:\users\john\.ssh\private.ppk`

[image]

[image]
[image]

### .

```
plink.exe -v -ssh %user@%proxyhost -P %proxyport -nc %host:%port   -i "c:\Users\john\.ssh\private.ppk"
```

---

**p.s.**

If your private key has password protect then you must additionaly launch pageant and load your private key there

---

**p.s.**

if you want to use command line only then:

```
putty.exe -proxycmd "plink.exe john@8.8.8.8 -P 22 -nc 172.16.0.21:22 -i c:\Users\john\.ssh\private.ppk " john@172.16.0.21  -i c:\Users\john\.ssh\private.ppk
```

Comment: You achieve the same *"SSH proxy"* feature in a way more simple way.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to start putty.exe from commandline it works this way:

```
putty.exe -proxycmd "plink.exe user@jumphost -P 22 -nc targethost:targetport" user@foo
```

According to the docs it uses stdin/stout of the proxycmd so "foo" is ok as target hostname here.