# Run Windows Script with several tunnels for Linux

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a Script in Linux with several tunnels for several servers and run a script in that servers.

Basically i've a DailyCheck.sh in 8 machines RedHat and i've a tunnel for each one in windows with:

```
"putty.exe user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -pw  <password> -L port:127.0.0.1:port"
```

And i open each one and run the command DailyCheck.sh.

What i want is one file in Windows with:

```
"putty.exe user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -pw  <password> -L port:127.0.0.1:port"
sudo su -
./dailyCheck.sh
<delay if necessary>
"putty.exe user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -pw  <password> -L port:127.0.0.1:port"
sudo su -
./dailyCheck.sh
(....)
```

we have any way to do this?

Thanks & Best Regards,
André.

Comment: With `cygwin` you can achieve this: https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i need to do this in the Windows CommandLine.
I need to do the ./dailyCheck inside the machine after the tunnel is open.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29168936/2451006

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you would - instead of tunnels - set up [proxy command](http://blog.terminal.com/setting-up-putty-with-terminals-ssh-proxy/) for each host. Then use [remote command execution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116674) to run the script on remote.

Also, to get better answers, I recommend tags [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) and [putty](/questions/tagged/putty).