# Can I tunnel a connection using Windows Server 2008

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, tunneling

I have a client that has some data that I need to process. This data is in a closed server that can only be accessed by a Windows Server 2008 server instance, via a specific port on the closed server.

My idea is to create a tunnel that forwards whatever comes from that port to me, although I have no idea of the feasibility of my plan.

1. Windows Server 2008 instance connects to closed server via socket.
2. Windows Server 2008 exposes a port that forwards the received data.
3. I connect to this newly exposed port.

Constraints: I cannot install anything on the Windows Server 2008 instance, so I am left with configuration tweaks and PowerShell scripts.

Is it possible to do this?

I have a lot of experience with Linux servers but none with Windows, I am researching ways to do this, but maybe someone can light the path on what I should look into.

Comment: What kind of traffic are you trying to proxy?

Comment: It's a log stream that goes through a specific port

Comment: So just text data over TCP on some random port?

Comment: That's exactly it

Comment: This blog details a serialized proxy, might be a little more than what you're after, but worth a check: https://learn-powershell.net/2014/02/22/building-a-tcp-server-using-powershell/

Comment: I guess you could do this, but why wouldn't you just [use PuTTY/plink to set up an SSH tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974131/how-to-create-ssh-tunnel-using-putty-in-windows)?  MyEnTunnel is another option, though it's kind of an amateurish operation, IIRC.