# How to ssh hop through multiple hosts from a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, ssh, cmd, putty, plink

How write a Windows batch file to be run from HostA for those connections below?

SSH (with local port forwarding): HostA => HostB => HostC.

HostA – HostB must use `plink.exe` (HostA runs Windows)
HostB – HostC must use `ssh` (HostB runs Linux).

I try this:

```
@echo off
chdir /d "C:\"
start plink.exe user_at_B@192.168.IP_of_B -pw userBpasswd
ssh -L user_at_C@192.168.IP_of_C
```

This batch script does not execute a second `ssh` command (from B to C), it just opens a new CMD window in which nothing happens.

Please disregard password storage in a batch file for `plink`.

Comment: You appear to be using `start` with `plink.exe`, which means that the command is started and immediately runs the next line, `ssh ...`, _(effectively both lines are being ran at the same time)_. I'm sure that is not what you want it to do, you'll either need to run one after the other, i.e. using `/Wait` or joining them as one command. The answer you've already received, chooses the latter.

Comment: @Compo `ssh` to work as OP intended, must be executed on the server, not locally. So it's was not my *choice*, imo it must be that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell `plink` to execute the `ssh`, by passing the `ssh` command to `plink` commandline:

```
start plink.exe -t user_at_B@192.168.IP_of_B -pw userBpasswd ssh -L user_at_C@192.168.IP_of_C
```

When the command is provided on Plink command-line, Plink by default does not use a terminal emulation. To force the terminal emulation, the [`-t` switch needs](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty) to be added (as shown above).

---

Though:

- Imo, your `ssh` command is wrong – With `-L` you need to specify an additional argument.
- For SSH hop, you can also use a port forwarding, instead of executing `ssh` on the intermediate server.
  See [How to create SSH tunnel using PuTTY in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974131/850848#29168936)

Comment: for 

`start plink.exe user_at_B@192.168.IP_of_B -pw userBpasswd ssh user_at_C@192.168.IP_of_C`

I get "pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal" error.

P.S. -L is for port forwarding, which I use.

Comment: Why do you think, it's an error? That's for information only, isn't it? + I know what `-L` does. That's why I know that it needs an argument, right?

Comment: yes yes :)
so how do I make this terminal alocation message sorted?

Comment: Depends, on what you mean by *"sorted"*. If you want to get rid of the message, you can try adding `-T` switch to `ssh`.

Comment: I mean `plink.exe userB@IPofB ssh userC@IPofC` does not work, stdin message is displayed and cmd Terminal closes :)
oh and this message is shown too: "Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)."
I am guessing this is related to ssh password request.

Comment: OK, so add `-t` switch to Plink (and do NOT add the `-T` to `ssh`)

Comment: yes, got it working, thanks @Martin
`plink.exe -t B@IP_B ssh C@IP_C`