# ssh port forwarding with flask

Tags: python, flask, ssh, ssh-tunnel

**TL;DR** `http.server` works with [port forwarding over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974248/2601293), but `flask` does not.

I'm having problems with flask and port forwarding.  I'm using putty to forward port 5000 to a windows client via ssh. When I use `python3 -m http.server 5000`, I can access the on the windows client by going to `http://localhost:5000`.  When I use flask, I can access it locally but not remotely from the windows client.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Web App with Python Flask!'
```

**Running flask**
`flask --app app run`

The error I'm getting is **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

There is another stackoverflow question [Configure Flask dev server to be visible across the network](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7023052/2601293) that is similar but does not address the issue at hand.  I don't have a remote connection here since I'm tunneling in over ssh. As far as flask is concerned, this connection is coming in locally.  Additionally, using the excepted answer of `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` still does not work in my case.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe flask runs on different port? ie. 8080. OR maybe flask doesn't work at this moment when you try to use tunelling.

Comment: @furas that is the full error message. While the tunnel is active, I can still access it on port 5000

Comment: I don't use Windows so I can't test it. But `flask` works corectly when I use forwarding `ssh -L 5000:localhost:5000` on Linux

Comment: @furas using a ssh tunnel in wsl works but putty does not.